# How to load page with url parameters on tab click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-tabs

I have page that has 5 different tabs. All of them load at the same time in the current code. This is not very efficient since I'm loading five files at the same time. Instead, I would like to load only one (default) on the first initial page load. The rest of the tabs I would like to load with ajax/jquery on click. Here is example of my current code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h4>Company Profile</h4>
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs" id="company_tabs" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#page_1">Page 1</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#page_2">Page 2</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#page_3">Page 3</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#page_4">Page 4</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#page_5">Page 5</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#page_6">Page 6</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="page_1" class="tab-pane active">
          <cfinclude template="page_1.html">
        </div>
        <div id="page_2" class="container tab-pane fade">
          <cfinclude template="page_2.html">
        </div>
        <div id="page_3" class="container tab-pane fade">
          <cfinclude template="page_3.html">
        </div>
        <div id="page_4" class="container tab-pane fade">
          <cfinclude template="page_4.html">
        </div>
        <div id="page_5" class="container tab-pane fade">
          <cfinclude template="page_5.html">
        </div>
        <div id="page_6" class="container tab-pane fade">
          <cfinclude template="page_6.html">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to load each html file on click. Only Page 1 should be loaded by default when user opens the page first time. All other tabs should be loaded on click. I use JQuery and Bootstrap 4 for this project.

Comment: where is your ajax? have you tried something? you have ids for each tab, either create a switch or function for each id click,  and load respective view via ajax

Comment: You're using `cfinclude`, so the pages will be included on the server side. Depending on your use case it's possible this is more efficient than rendering one smaller page and having the users send multiple request to load more information. If you really want to do it that way, research AJAX.

Comment: how look page_1.html? for example ... (is it a complete html page ?)

Comment: @MisterJojo It can be simple as `<h1>Hello, this is Page 1</h1>`

Comment: Should be as simple as leaving the content of each tab empty and just create an onclick event on each tab with `$( "#page_x" ).load( "your_content.html" );` Though to be honest, if my internet is so extremely slow that I notice a difference in loading a few html pages, I rather just wait a little longer 1 time than everytime I open a new tab. But that's just me..